# AJAX to WCF not working in FireFox

Tags: wcf, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to get [this sample](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/JSON-EnabledWCFServicesInASPNET35.aspx) for AJAX to WCF working, with the following code.  When viewed in FF, nothing is displayed, and when viewed in IE, the time is displayed.
I'm using IIS 7, btw.

```
    function getTime() {            
        TimeService.TimeService.GetTimeFormatted("dd-mm-yyyy [hh:mm:ss]", onMethodCompleted, onMethodFailed);
    }

    function onMethodCompleted(results) {
        $get("currentTimeLabel").innerText = results;        
    }
```

...

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used MS AJAX, but as far as I can tell,

```
function getTime() {            
    TimeService.TimeService.GetTimeFormatted("dd-mm-yyyy [hh:mm:ss]", onMethodCompleted, onMethodFailed);
}
```

That right there seems like it'll run an aync invoke on GetTimeFormatted, and pass the results on to "onMethodCompleted"..

```
function onMethodCompleted(results) {
    $get("currentTimeLabel").innerText = getTime();        
}
```

Will, for every time it gets invoked, re-invoke the getTime method.. So what you're doing is starting a loop of asynchronous invokes.

It **seems** to me (noted that I've not used ms ajax..)  that you should probably have something more like..

```
function getTime()
{      
    var onComplete = function(results) { $get("currentTimeLabel").innerText = results; }
    TimeService.TimeService.GetTimeFormatted("dd-mm-yyyy [hh:mm:ss]", onComplete , onMethodFailed);
}
```

And then invoke the getTime method when you want the results updated.

Comment: Thanks!  I should have picked up the cascade when I opened the FireBug console to look at another error.

Comment: Now it's working in IE but not FF.  Changed the subject line of the question.